# Creating a File with Ruby + extension is not working

Tags: ruby, file

I want to create a file, where the user can create a custom name and then the file extension .txt should get added. But kinda it is not working to create this file..
After that i would like to outprint the message that the file got created in one line, but it gets returned with breakes after the outprint the file_name..
Any ideas how to fix this?

```
def t_anlegen
      print "Telefonbuchname: "
      file_name = gets.to_s
      file_name = file_name + ".txt"
      write_handler = File.new(file_name,"w")
      write_handler.close
      "[!]" + file_name + "wurde erfolgreich erstellt!"
end
```

Comment: You need to replace `\n` with `file_name = gets.chomp`.

Comment: @zeitnot thanks, now its working!

Comment: Interpolation is more useful than concatenation. For example you can use `"[!] #{file_name} wurde erfolgreich erstellt!"`

Comment: @mechnicov do you know why 
`write_handler = File.delete(file_name)
write_handler.close`
causes a crash?

Comment: [`File.delete`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/File.html#method-c-delete) returns `Integer`. If you have question it's better to open new one. Comments are moderated and can be deleted.

Comment: "kinda it is not working to create this file" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. What does "kinda" mean? *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All data from command line, which you take with `gets` is `String`. So you don't need to use `to_s`.

When you type any words you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. It produces `"\n"` in the end of `String`.

To remove it use [`String#chomp`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/String.html#method-i-chomp-21).

In your case

```
file_name = gets.chomp
```